# How to sort tabularx enteries in Latex?

Tags: sorting, latex

I have a tabularx in my file like this:

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c p{0.5cm} Y}
      RFID & & Radio Frequency ID\cr
      WSN & & Wireless Sensor Network\cr
      IoT & & Internet of Things\cr
      SN & & Sensor Network\cr
      IEEE & & Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers        
 \end{tabularx}
```

I would like to know if there is any command that sorts the output of the tabularx in pdf, alphabetically, to get an output like:

List of Acronyms:

- IEEE    Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers
- IoT     Internet of Things
- RFID    Radio Frequency ID
- SN      Sensor Network
- WSN     Wireless Sensor Network

Comment: There are dedicated tools to create list of acronyms - they will automatically sort the entries. For example have a look at the `glossaries` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead if reinventing the wheel, I suggest to use one of the existing package to create lists of acronyms. One example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[]{glossaries}       
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{RFID}{RFID}{Radio Frequency ID}
\newacronym{WSN}{WSN}{Wireless Sensor Network}
\newacronym{IoT}{IoT}{Internet of Things}
\newacronym{SN}{SN}{Sensor Network}
\newacronym{IEEE}{IEEE}{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}


\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={List of Acronyms},nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

(to be compiled with `pdflatex filename ; makeglossaries filename ; pdflatex filename`)

[image]